# Complex CSV parsing with Linux commands

Tags: csv, awk, sed, command-line

I have a CSV log file that records the properties `HA;HB;HC;HD;HE`. The following file records 6 entries (separated by the above header).

I would like to extract the 3rd property(`HC`) of every entry.

```
HA;HB;HC;HD;HE
a1;b1;14;d;e
HA;HB;HC;HD;HE
a2;b2;28;d;e
HA;HB;HC;HD;HE
a31;b31;44;d;e
a32;b32;07;d;e
HA;HB;HC;HD;HE
a4;b4;0;d;e
HA;HB;HC;HD;HE
a51;b51;32;d;e
a52;b52;0;d;e
a53;b53;5;d;e
HA;HB;HC;HD;HE
a6;b6;10;d;e
```

Whenever there's `n` lines of `HC` recorded per entry, I want to extract the addition of the `n` entries.

The expected output for the above file:

```
14
28
51
0
37
10
```

I know I can write a program for this, but is there an easy way to get this with a combination on `awk` and/or `sed` commands?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this; try it and let me know if it works.

```
awk -F';' '
    $3 == "HC" {
        if (NR > 1) {
            print sum
            sum = 0 }
        next }
    { sum += $3 }
    END { print sum }'
```

Comment: This returns 7 zeros.. But let me play a little bit with this idea and see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

awk solution:

```
$ awk -F';' '$3=="HC" && p{
    print sum          # print current total
    sum=p=0            # reinitialize sum and p
    next
 }
 $3!="HC"{
    sum=sum+($3+0)     # make sure $3 is converted to integer. sum it up.
    p=1                # set p to 1               
 }                     # print last sum
 END{print sum}' input.txt
```

output:

```
14
28
51
0
37
10
```

one-liner:

```
$ awk -F";" '$3=="HC" && p{print sum;sum=p=0;next} $3!="HC"{sum=sum+($3+0);p=1} END{print sum}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F';' '/^H.*/{if(f)print s;s=0;f=$3=="HC"}f{s+=$3}END{if(f)print s}' infile
```

For given inputs:

```
$ cat infile
HA;HB;HC;HD;HE
a1;b1;14;d;e
HA;HB;HC;HD;HE
a2;b2;28;d;e
HA;HB;HC;HD;HE
a31;b31;44;d;e
a32;b32;07;d;e
HA;HB;HC;HD;HE
a4;b4;0;d;e
HA;HB;HC;HD;HE
a51;b51;32;d;e
a52;b52;0;d;e
a53;b53;5;d;e
HA;HB;HC;HD;HE
a6;b6;10;d;e

$ awk -F';' '/^H.*/{if(f)print s; s=0; f=$3=="HC"}f{s+=$3}END{if(f)print s}' infile
14
28
51
0
37
10
```

It takes little more care for example:

```
$ cat infile2
HA;HB;HC;HD;HE
a1;b1;14;d;e
HA;HB;HC;HD;HE
a2;b2;28;d;e
HA;HB;HC;HD;HE
a31;b31;44;d;e
a32;b32;07;d;e
HA;HB;HC;HD;HE
a4;b4;0;d;e
HA;HB;HD;HD;HE         <---- Say if HC does not found
a51;b51;32;d;e
a52;b52;0;d;e
a53;b53;5;d;e
HA;HB;HC;HD;HE
a6;b6;10;d;e

# find only HC in 3rd column
$ awk -F';' '/^H.*/{if(f)print s; s=0; f=$3=="HC"}f{s+=$3}END{if(f)print s}' infile2
14
28
51
0
10

# Find HD in 3rd column
$ awk -F';' '/^H.*/{if(f)print s; s=0; f=$3=="HD"}f{s+=$3}END{if(f)print s}' infile2
37
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eval "true || $(cat data.csv|cut -d ";" -f3 |sed -e s/"HC"/"0; expr 0"/g |tr '\n' '@'|sed -e s/"@@"/""/g|sed -e s/"@"/" + "/g)"
```

**Explanation:**

1. Get contents of the file using `cat`
2. Take only the third column using `cut` delimiter of `;`
3. Replace `HC` lines with `0; expr 0` values to start building `eval`-worthy bash expressions to eventually yield `expr 0 + 14;`
4. Replace `\n` newlines temporarily with `@` to circumvent possible BSD `sed` limitations
5. Replace double `@@` with single `@` to avoid blank lines turning into spaces and causing `expr` to bomb out.
6. Replace `@` with `+` to add the numbers together.
7. Execute the command, but with a `true || 0; expr ...` to avoid a guaranteed syntax error on the first line.

Which creates this:

```
true || 0; expr 0 + 14 + 0; expr 0 + 28 + 0; expr 0 + 44 + 07 + 0; expr 0 + 0 + 0; expr 0 + 32 + 0 + 5 + 0; expr 0 + 10
```

The output looks like this:

```
14
28
51
0
37
10
```

This was tested on Bash 3.2 and MacOS El Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -F";" '
/^H/ && $3!="HC"{
  flag="";
  next
}
/^H/ && $3=="HC"{
  if(NR>1){
    printf("%d\n",sum)
};
  sum=0;
  flag=1;
  next
}
flag{
  sum+=$3
}
END{
  printf("%d\n",sum)
}
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
14
28
51
0
37
10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F';' '$3=="HC"{if (NR>1) print s; s=0; next} {s+=$3} END{print s}' file
14
28
51
0
37
10
```